# 100% height and box-shadow

Tags: html, css

Hello I've been trying to make my main container have a shadow, but since I don't have a fixed size in height seems to be a problem with it, so It won't display any shadow, the page im doing is more like template that's why I don't want to have a fixed size, got any suggestion?

Comment: Would adding a `min-height:1px` do anything?

Comment: Post your code. Is it certain browsers that it's not working for? All browsers? It seems to work fine here in webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/VTHPu/

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the width and height using javascript, after the page has been rendered, then add the box-shadow and set the width/height.